# Fedora 24 freezes randomly

Tags: fedora, freeze

I have Acer Aspire E5 laptop. From Ubuntu I shifted to Fedora 23. Then sometimes I faced the problem of freezing.

Recently I upgraded to Fedora 24. After a few days, the same problem arose in much more severe form. After using the system for 20 to 30 minutes it freezes; my keyboard and touchpad do not work.

My question: is it a hardware problem of my laptop or some software issue caused by improper installing?

Comment: without any logs, kernel dumps or any relevant information, it is not possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at [this](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94101) bug report - the freeze might be related to a problem with in the RC6 support which can be deactivated in the boot loader (`grub`). I don't know if the i3-4005U supports RC6 but I've experienced similar problems on a Skylake i5.

In case RC6 is the problem you can try [this](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94101#c13) approach:

1. as `root`, edit `/etc/default/grub`
2. find the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`

   - append `i915.enable_rc6=0`
   - example: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rhgb quiet i915.enable_rc6=0"`
3. Apply the changes

   - [Updating GRUB 2 on BIOS systems](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2?rd=Grub2#Updating_GRUB_2_configuration_on_BIOS_systems)
   - [Updating GRUB 2 on UEFI systems](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2?rd=Grub2#Updating_GRUB_2_configuration_on_UEFI_systems)
4. Reboot / Test

Note: to test this approach you can simply edit your `grub` config file (find it with `find /boot -iname \*.cfg` as `root` and edit the long line starting with s.th. like `linuxefi` in the first menu entry)

---

*Generally* you can do the following to get more information to post here:

after system startup launch a terminal and run:

```
dmesg -w
```

keep the window visible all the time and wait for the crash to happen. This will wait for kernel logs and print them immediately.

*Sometimes* you can see some kernel vomit before the crash which might give you a hint or you can post here.

If there are no messages printed this might be an important info, too.

Comment: Can you help me how to resolve bugs ? I have seen the the link , but could not find anything helpful . @frans

Comment: I've added some more info - note that this particular approach only works if you use the `i915` kernel driver. Have you tried capturing some kernel message using `dmesg -w`?

Comment: my problem is partially resolved . I guess, problem is in gnome environment . I changed it to openbox . Though it is not so user-friendly . But it works with no freezing still .